# Docker with Angular 4 and Django is compiled successfully but localhost:4200 is not working

Tags: python, django, angular, typescript, docker

I would like to dockerize Angular 4 frontend with Django backend and postgresql database. At this moment my files looks as shown below. I am note sure if this is done properly? When I try `docker-compose up` I get information that both frontend with Angular 4 and backend with Django started successfully. Unfortunately when I open http://localhost:4200 it doesn't work (localhost:8001 seems working):

```
django_1   | Django version 1.11, using settings 'project.settings'
django_1   | Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8001/
django_1   | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
angular_1  | ** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200 **                                                             
angular_1  | Time: 20657ms
angular_1  | chunk    {0} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 232 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
angular_1  | chunk    {1} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 222 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
angular_1  | chunk    {2} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 11.6 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
angular_1  | chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 4.41 MB [initial] [rendered]
angular_1  | chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]
angular_1  | webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

Structure of my files:

```
├── Backend
│   ├── AI
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   └── manage.py
├── Dockerfile
├── Frontend
│   └── angularProject
        ├── Dockerfile
│       └── all files in my angular project 
├── docker-compose.yml
└── requirements.txt
```

`Dockerfile` from frontend:

```
# Create image based on the official Node 6 image from dockerhub
FROM node:6

# Create a directory where our app will be placed
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

# Change directory so that our commands run inside this new directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy dependency definitions
COPY package.json /usr/src/app

# Install dependecies
RUN npm install

# Get all the code needed to run the app
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Expose the port the app runs in
EXPOSE 4200

# Serve the app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

`Dockerfile` from main directory:

```
FROM python:3.6.1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: aso
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: somepass
  django:
    build: .
    command: python3 MainDirectory/backend/myProject/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    depends_on:
      - db
  angular:
    build: MainDirectory/frontend
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    depends_on:
      - django
```

Answer (score 1):

The server is running on port 4200 but you're exposing port 80 on 8010 with:

```
  angular:
    build: MainDirectory/frontend
    ports:
      - "8010:80"  # <==== HERE
    depends_on:
      - django
```

You should probably use:

```
  angular:
    build: MainDirectory/frontend
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    depends_on:
      - django
```

You might also have to get your server (`npm start` script) to bind on `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: I have changed ports in angular to `- "4200:4200"` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Does it timeout or do you get a server error? Did you change the binding?

Comment: `safari can't open the page because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection` I have changed only ports as shown in updated post.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Safari, but it sounds like it's able to connect to the server now and the issue has changed. Progress! Try using Safari developer tools, angular logs, and/or Wireshark to figure out why the server is dropping the connection. There should be an error logged somewhere to help pinpoint the new issue.

Comment: In google chrome I get `This page isn’t working. localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`